# Fullcalendar Plugin Error - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to use the fullcalendar plugin in my angular project but it is not working.

I have all the required files pointed at:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/plugins/dataTables/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/plugins/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js_test/plugins/fullcalendar/calendar.js"></script>
```

This is my app_test:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('schoolAdminPortal', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'ui.calendar'
    ])
})();
```

Error:
[image]

Configuration:

```
$scope.events = [
        {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, 1)},
        {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
        {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false},
        {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
        {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
        {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
    ];
```

Comment: It looks like a wrong configuration in fullcalendar events. Could you provide us your fullcalendar configuration?

Comment: @MarioLevrero I have added the events

Comment: Your error is referencing your calendar.js file lines 87 and 55. Check in that line that you don't have an undefined object in which you make a `yourObject.length`